# C# Program Runs in Debug Mode but not Directly by the Executable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, kill

Hi everyone.

I am trying to create a program in C# that edits a file using a graphical interface.  I have done this type of thing before many times without fail, but this time was different.  I was able to debug it fine, but when I went directly to the executable file in its folder it did not open.  It showed no sign of even running.

Curious about this phenomenon I looked in task manager and it did not show up.  I tried to delete the file, but it said:

> This action can't be completed because the file is open in  System
>
> Close the file and try again

I could not find "System" this in task manager so I when to Resource Monitor.
I found my program open in there (not under System), so I tried to kill the process.  That resulted in the following dialog box:

> When attempting to execute the command, the following system error occurred:
>
> Access is denied.

I went online and tried to download programs that would kill the process automatically, but to no avail.  They all gave me errors similar to the "Access Denied" error stated above.

Things I've Tried:

1. Kill the process
2. Reinstall the .NET library selected in the project properties
3. Restarting my computer

The only thing out of those three that worked was restarting my computer.  This released the executable and I was able to delete it and recompile my program, but as soon as I would run it the same thing repeated its self.

My program features heavy graphics, multiple threads, and references to multiple libraries.  I do not know if any of these are causing this problem, but I thought that I might include them anyway.

Like I said before, I have done this type of thing before, but I do not know what I am doing wrong now.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: By any chance do you have an antivirus program? It could be some sort of conflict. Try testing with the antivirus on and off. Maybe don't go online to prevent viruses and intrusions

Comment: Also try running as administrator...

Comment: Wow, I just tried what you said and it worked like a charm! Is there any way that you know that I can run my program with antivirus on?

Comment: Wait, I just tried to delete it and it says that it is still open in system.  I can now open it, but it will not let me rebuild the solution because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your debug folder as an exception to your antivirus path, that should prevent it from intercepting the execution.

For your "Still open in system" errors, I don't know. It could be that your antivirus automatically quarantined it? You could try to delete or at least rename your EXE file or the files involved using something that goes low-level, like [PC Hunter](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/pc_hunter.html) (I've tried it before without any problems, but still I take no responsibility whatsoever). Or if it that freaks you out, just restart your PC and rename your file if that works, and placing the folder on your antivirus's exception list will probably prevent it from happening again.

Comment: Thanks, I just put it on my scan exception list and it works now.  Thank you.